# Text from <li> into tag in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got an unordered list and some `<li>` elements in. `<li>`'s are text.
I also have `<input>` field on my website. All work as drag&drop elements - you can drag text from `<li>` and it appears as text in  after dropping it there.

Is there any way to convert text from `<li>` into tag in `<input>` field? Any jquery plugins? I tried tagmanager.js, but it creates tag after typing text and hitting enter.

I would like to have something like this: I drag text from `<li>` into `<input>` and it automatically converts into tag (for example span with text from `<li>`).
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What's handling the drag and drop functionality?

Comment: Sounds like you're providing a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all decent jQuery plugins will have an API to programatically execute their function. In your case, you're looking for a method you can call which allows you to programatically insert a tag into the input, without needing to type it out and press enter.

Assuming you meant [this tagmanager plugin](https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager), you can see under the "Tag Manager API Methods" section, there is a `pushTag` method you can call.

Your drag 'n' drop plugin will most certainly have a callback function for `onDrop` or similar. So you simply need to write a custom function for that event, which grabs the text from the `<li>` and calls the `pushTag` method on the tag manager instance.

All of the code you need for this is either really basic, or is well documented, so 2 minutes on google and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript drag and drop events.
Refer Docs,
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop